# Как задержать консоль при работе с Typescript в Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Пытаюсь в Visual Studio запустить код Typescript, но у меня сразу пропадает консоль, В С++ и подобных языках можно применить system("pause"). А в Typescript какая команда позволит задержать консоль?

Comment: Это явно проблема XY. Небось вы занимаетесь printf отладкой.

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже нашел решение. Простая команда debbuger решает проблему